# const char* classname::getname( ) const ? whats the meaning of first const keyword?

Tags: c++, c++11

I know second constant keyword tells function is constant

```
class Person{  
char *name;     
int age;  

public:  
const char* GetName() const;  
int GetAge() const;  

};
```

Comment: Without it, the return type will be pointer to non-const `char`; it's different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const char* GetName() const;
```

The first occurence of the `const` keyword in the above statement is in the data type of the return value of the function `GetName()`, which is also a constant function.

This means that the value returned by `GetName()` will be:

- of type `char`
- a pointer
- a `const` value

Since the return value will be `const`, `GetName()` will recieve a pointer to a constant `char` value. So if you have:

```
Person object;
const char* point = object.GetName();
```

`*point` will point to a constant `char` value.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `const char* point = object.GetName();` in your example?

Answer (score 3):

the pointer that you assign the pointer returned by the function, points to a `const` `char`

Answer (score 1):

It means that the function returns pointer to a constant `char`. Following will be a goodread for usage of `const` keyword in C++.

http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/const_correctness.html

Answer (score 1):

As it has been explained above, it says const pointer. It will work only for const pointers.

```
const char * p = GetName();  //Compiled successfully
char * p = getName(); //compilation error... however you can remove using const_cast)
```

`const char*` reflect that `char*` is constant. Therefore following line will give error:--

```
*p = 'c';
```

However P is not constant here. So you can write like :--

```
char ch;
p = &ch;
```

Usually when function returns the value, we are concerned about value (like it should not be modified). I hope it will help.